Reproducing the lichess opening tree stat bar

Can LaTeX offer something like this or the like shapes with same info?

You've received answers to a number of your previous questions but have yet to accept any. Please consider accepting answers which helped you while you are here. For this question, the answer is that yes, you can produce something like this using LaTeX.

Sorry for not accepting answers to my previous questions.
Just a moment.

The question is too open, it could be answered with very different approaches, but you do not clarify what is mandatory,  optional, or irrelevant in that image. Nobody wants to spend a lot of time making elaborated answers from scratch only to receive the feedback that is not good because there are no horses,  the background is not black,  the bars not have rounder corners, or is a plot but you want a table, ... or whatever.  It is better if you show the code of your best attempt to reproduce this and ask to solve  one specific issue to get closer to the goal.

One approach can be like thîs: table with 4 columns; in the last you put a \tikz{} statement (i.e. in each row); inside you draw the left and right node with rounded corners, and the middle one last to get the illusion of your "rounded bultibar".

You did not explain much about how exact the output should match the picture you provide, but something like this could be a starting point (the thin white lines in the output are rendering errors):
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\sisetup{number-mode=text, group-separator={,}}

\newlength{\statbarLeftWidth}
\newlength{\statbarMiddleWidth}
\newlength{\statbarRightWidth}
\colorlet{stat bar left text}{black!70}
\colorlet{stat bar middle text}{black!10}
\colorlet{stat bar right text}{black!10}
\colorlet{stat bar left fill}{black!40}
\colorlet{stat bar middle fill}{black!60}
\colorlet{stat bar right fill}{black!80}
\colorlet{stat bar left stroke}{black!50}
\colorlet{stat bar middle stroke}{black!70}
\colorlet{stat bar right stroke}{black!90}
\tikzset{
    pics/stat bar/.style n args={3}{
        code={
            \pgfmathsetlength{\statbarLeftWidth}{#1 / (#1 + #2 + #3) * 
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/stat bar/total width}}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\statbarMiddleWidth}{#2 / (#1 + #2 + #3) *  
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/stat bar/total width}}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\statbarRightWidth}{#3 / (#1 + #2 + #3) *  
                \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/stat bar/total width}}
            \node[
                stat bar/rounded corners left=
                    {stat bar left fill}{stat bar left stroke},
                text=stat bar left text,
                text width={\statbarLeftWidth},
                minimum height=1.2em,
                inner sep=0pt,
                align=center,
            ] (-left) {\qty{#1}{\percent}};
            \node[
                stat bar/rounded corners middle=
                    {stat bar middle fill}{stat bar middle stroke},
                text=stat bar middle text,
                text width={\statbarMiddleWidth},
                minimum height=1.2em,
                inner sep=0pt,
                align=center,
                anchor=west
            ] (-middle) at (-left.east) {\qty{#2}{\percent}};
            \node[
                stat bar/rounded corners right=
                    {stat bar right fill}{stat bar right stroke},
                text=stat bar right text,
                text width={\statbarRightWidth},
                minimum height=1.2em,
                inner sep=0pt,
                align=center,
                anchor=west
            ] (-right) at (-middle.east) {\qty{#3}{\percent}};
        }
    },
    stat bar/rounded corners left/.style 2 args={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \draw[
                    top color=#1!75!white, 
                    bottom color=#1, 
                    draw=#2
                ] (\tikzlastnode.east) 
                    |- (\tikzlastnode.south) 
                    { [rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/stat bar/corner radius}] 
                        -| (\tikzlastnode.west) 
                        |- (\tikzlastnode.north) 
                    } -| cycle;
            \endpgfextra
        } 
    },
    stat bar/rounded corners middle/.style 2 args={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \draw[
                    top color=#1!75!white, 
                    bottom color=#1, 
                    draw=#2
                ] (\tikzlastnode.north west) 
                    rectangle (\tikzlastnode.south east);
            \endpgfextra
        } 
    },
    stat bar/rounded corners right/.style 2 args={
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \draw[
                    top color=#1!75!white, 
                    bottom color=#1, 
                    draw=#2
                ] (\tikzlastnode.west) 
                    |- (\tikzlastnode.north) 
                    { [rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/stat bar/corner radius}] 
                        -| (\tikzlastnode.east) 
                        |- (\tikzlastnode.south) 
                    } -| cycle;
            \endpgfextra
        } 
    },
    stat bar/corner radius/.initial={3.5pt},
    stat bar/total width/.initial={10cm},
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={ l r r Q[l, wd=10.25cm] }, 
        row{odd}={black!80}, 
        row{even}={black!70},
        column{2-3}={font=\footnotesize},
        cells={fg=black!20},
        rowsep=5pt
    }
    
    e4 & \qty{45}{\percent} & \num{1138596} & 
        \tikz[baseline=(bar-left.base)]{ \pic (bar) {stat bar={33}{43}{25}} } \\

    d4 & \qty{36}{\percent} & \num{908461} & 
        \tikz[baseline=(bar-left.base)]{ \pic (bar) {stat bar={33}{44}{23}} } \\

    ♘f3 & \qty{10}{\percent} & \num{255179} & 
        \tikz[baseline=(bar-left.base)]{ \pic (bar) {stat bar={34}{44}{23}} } \\

    \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}


The idea with the rounded corners of the nodes was taken from this approach.

It could be simplified, I guess, but anyway … I stitched together some ideas.

Thanks.
But Yes I need much simpler way, but
the exact reproduction is really appreciated.

@WassimSaeed You could maybe also do this without using a \pic, but if you want to create the table with TikZ as well, for example, it is better to use a \pic since you can easily use it inside a tikzpicture. For other use cases, you could also just use \nodes of course.
